# <Label> tag alternative for Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have the following Problem

I get a variable from PHP via:

```
echo $var
```

Actually this takes place in:

```
<a href:"..\test.php?go=<?php echo $var ?>">
```

And to a page where you can get more info about `$var`...

Today i learned about the `display` attribute from a div, so i can display the info via Ajax direct in my actual page. So, I tried:

```
<Label id="123" onclick="doJS(<?php echo $var ?>)> Click ME </Label>
```

But this doesn't work, I cant click the label, just nothing happens.
How can this be solved?

Comment: What the developer console shows? Can you post the doJS() function?

Comment: Is $var numeric or text?

Comment: $var is like "007A09"... is this relevant?

Where do i can find a developer's console?
I use Dreamweaver, but it gives no error. 
It was a Typo, see below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your code.

Replace

```
<Label id="123" onclick="doJS(<?php echo $var ?>)> Click ME </Label>
```

By

```
<Label id="123" onclick="doJS(<?php echo $var ?>)"> Click ME </Label>
```

Comment: Don't forget, if the function argument accepts a string then it will need to be quoted.

Comment: I know this :) i will copy the JS from a addBasket-Button i use :) Thanks:!

Answer (score 0):

So you should try:

```
<label id='123' onclick="doJS(<?=$_GET['go']?>)"> Click ME </label>
```